# cURL Error: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have a system foe my personal use, but in the last days just got the error "cURL Error: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to [www.comprasnet.gov.br:443"](http://www.comprasnet.gov.br:443%22).
Coincidentally the above URL got Unsecure minutes before this error shown up.
[Unsafe/Unsecure website][1]
Im not a programmer, so if anyone could help me out. I tried a lot of things in the internet but with no luck.
Here's the code i'm using: I'm usaing wampp and run this in localhost

````
$ch = curl_init();
// opcoes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//$cookiefile = dirname(__FILE__)."/cookie.php" ; 
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);

//executar sessao
$output = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($output === FALSE) {               // verifica erros no curl
           echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
        }
$output = strtr($output, $conversao); // função de conversão acentuado/não acentuado
//fechar sessao
curl_close($ch);```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3xlA.png
````

Comment: You say: _"Coincidentally the above URL got Unsecure minutes before this error shown up."_. What does that mean? Are you saying the SSL certificate expired for www.comprasnet.gov.br?

Comment: That's the problem the certificate is not expired, but when i access this website in any browser, it says: your conection to this website isn't secure. And the HTTPS got a risk in it.

Comment: The website you're trying to access should work properly before you try to access it using CURL in PHP.

Comment: I tried `http://` instead of `https://` and that seems to work?

Comment: There's a long discussion about the CA [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1677631) and [here](https://groups.google.com/a/ccadb.org/g/public/c/Mux855BsRg4/m/VVoTWfmQHgAJ), and it sounds like they're trying to get listed publicly but the community isn't confident in the responses. At this point, any attempts at accessing hosts with that root CA might fail, and short of ignoring security completely, I'm not certain you can fix this on your side of things.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I tried changing it, but no luck.

Comment: Does _"no luck"_ mean you still get the error: "cURL Error: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.comprasnet.gov.br:443"? Or does it mean you tried to change it, but you couldn't?

Comment: Still get the error.

Comment: That's weird. The error should, at least, have changed. Port 443 is used by `https://` whereas port 80 is used by `http://`.